# Rmail Beginner, where do I start?

Tags: email

Suppose I have a gmail account, say *foo@gmail.com* with a password: *foopassword*.

- What are the simplest steps to go through, to read my emails?
- Does it make any difference whether I'm using Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked in the documentation for it? There's a whole chapter about *Rmail* in the [*Emacs* manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rmail.html#Rmail) (you can also access this and other manuals from within *Emacs* by typing `C-h i`).

I've never used **Rmail** before, but from reading the first few paragraphs I can tell you that the only difference between *Windows* and *Linux* that matters will be the way that *Rmail* finds and runs the `movemail` command. On *Linux* it will probably find it on its own, but on *MS Windows* you'll probably have to configure the variable `rmail-movemail-program` or `rmail-movemail-search-path` to tell it where to find it.

Comment: Actually I read the documentation, and other resources on the web, but nothing worked, I just want a simple plain example to start with.

Comment: You'll probably have to ask more specific questions then, with specific details of what you've tried and how it failed ("nothing worked" isn't going to get you anywhere). It should be as simple as setting the variable `rmail-primary-inbox-list` to a list with one string in it, where that string contains the url to your IMAP server. Something like this: `(setq rmail-primary-inbox-list '("imaps://username:password@your-imap-server"))` and then running rmail with `M-x rmail`.

Comment: That's what I entend to do.